# How to get the preview image from HLS(live stream) data source

Tags: java, android, kotlin, http-live-streaming

- I have 2 data sources one is `MP4` and another `HLS`
- Both data sources are stored on the server
- I am able to generate the preview from an MP4 source using a metadata
  retriever

***code to get a preview from mp4***

```
val metaDataRetriever = MediaMetadataRetriever()
metaDataRetriever.setDataSource(url,HashMap())

val timeInMilliSecond = 20000

val request = Glide.with(context)
    .load(metaDataRetriever.getFrameAtTime(timeInMilliSecond))
    .override(thumbNailWidth, height)
    .centerCrop()
```

- But If I give the HLS data source, I am not able to get the preview

**Question**: How to get the preview image from `HLS` data source

Comment: did you managed to solve it? I have the same problem

Comment: @jack_the_beast. Check my answer !

Answer (score 1):

***I ended up using the MP4 preview itself***

- Anyone looking for something similar and check [this --> link](https://github.com/wseemann/FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever)
- I have not to use the above link but maybe it will help

Comment: It's definitively the way to go. however i't not ideal in some cases since it requires to initialize the player to get the manifest. So if you have a list of videos, it's not recommended for performance reasons